# Characters charset from sub module wrong in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, module, character-encoding

I have an android app in Android Studio which was imported from eclipse.
Beside the android module the project contains java modules.

The java modules handle charsets wrong, the android module does correct.
I have this method implemented in an Activity and also in an sub-module class:

```
public String getUmlaute() {
    return "öäüßÖÄÜ " + Charset.defaultCharset();
}
```

This

```
submoduleClass.getUmlaute() + "--" + getUmlaute();
```

returns

```
Ã¶Ã¤Ã¼ÃŸÃ–Ã„Ãœ java.nio.charset.CharsetICU[UTF-8] -- öäüßÖÄÜ java.nio.charset.CharsetICU[UTF-8]
```

All files are UTF-8 encoded of cause. Android Studio and also notepad++ confirm this and also the correctness of the letters.

Android Studio Settings[image: Android Studio Settings]

I tried both, clear the subproject default encoding and set it to UTF-8. No difference.

Whats going wrong here? Is there an encoding option missing?

Comment: OK, I have to create a bug report, i think. I created a new Android Project, created a java module within and this app shows the same behavior.

Comment: Bugreport at: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=163547

Comment: The problem does not exist on my linux machine. Unfortunately I have to use windows at work. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 5):

Finally solved, but weired.
I added

```
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
```

to every java build.gradle file.

I added

```
android {
    compileOptions.encoding = "UTF-8"
```

to the android build.gradle file.

In "Settings"->File Encodings I set the Default Encoding of the Java Modules to windows-1252.

That did the trick.
The files are still utf-8

Maybe its a windows file system problem. This is NTFS by the way.